# I want to update my iPhone 5s from iOS 9 to iOS 10, not iOS 11. Is it possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, software-update

My iphone currently runs on ios 9.2. I want to update it to ios 10 so that I can use an app I need for school. I dont want to update to ios 11 yet though. Is it possible to update to an earlier version of ios or do i just have to update to ios 11? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**No, this is no longer possible.** While you may have previously downloaded iOS 10, or may be able to download it through other online sources, installing it is no longer possible as Apple has stopped *signing* installations of iOS 10.

Typically, when a new version of iOS launches, the window for installing the previous version of iOS is *about* two weeks.